# Not able to update Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit; getting error message in the end (Dell DULX0035)

Tags: 16.04, dell

when I do update and upgrade, I am getting the following error.

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/boomaga/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A02ACCC9C6DAEA80
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/boomaga/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F172854044A3B98
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have checked also the source list. It looks everything fine. 
But still I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to `System Settings`->`Software & Updates`. Then select the `Ubuntu Software` tab and uncheck these items;

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/boomaga/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

After unchekcing these items, run `sudo apt update` and you'll be able to update your system onwards.

Comment: Update is working now! but during the upgrade, I am getting the following error.     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Can you please give the full error message that you get while upgrading. This is to check which package is causing trouble while upgrading.